# Get parameter value if parameter annotation exists

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, ejb, interceptor

Is it possible to get the value of a parameter if an annotation is present on that parameter?

Given EJB with parameter-level annotations:

```
public void fooBar(@Foo String a, String b, @Foo String c) {...}
```

And an interceptor:

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object doIntercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    // Get value of parameters that have annotation @Foo
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `doIntercept()` you can retrieve the method being called from the `InvocationContext` and get the [parameter annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterAnnotations%28%29).

```
Method method = context.getMethod();
Annotation[][] annotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
Object[] parameterValues = context.getParameters();

// then iterate through parameters and check if annotation exists at each index, example with first parameter at index 0:
if (annotations[0].length > 0 /* and add check if the annotation is the type you want */) 
    // get the value of the parameter
    System.out.println(parameterValues[0]);
```

Because the `Annotation[][]` returns an empty 2nd dimension array if there are no Annotations, you know which parameter positions have the annotations. You can then call [`InvocationContext#getParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html#getParameters%28%29) to get a `Object[]` with the values of all the parameters passed. The size of this array and the `Annotation[][]` will be the same. Just return the value of the indices where there are no annotations.

Comment: That will only give me the annotations present on the parameters. What I need is the value of the parameter given the annotation is present.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to fetch any attributes on the annotation Foo. Rather, I want the values of the parameters. In my example above, I want the values of arguments a and c.

Comment: @user2664820 Yeah, just updated. The `method.getParameterAnnotations();` will tell you which positions and the `context.getParameters()` will give you the value

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this,I define a Param annotation named MyAnnotation and I get the Param annotation in this way. It works.

```
Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
Class[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();

int i=0;
for(Annotation[] annotations : parameterAnnotations){
  Class parameterType = parameterTypes[i++];

  for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof MyAnnotation){
        MyAnnotation myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation) annotation;
        System.out.println("param: " + parameterType.getName());
        System.out.println("value: " + myAnnotation.value());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some information why your code solves the problem. Please look at [answer]

Comment: @JimHawkins Thanks for your tips.This is my first time to answer and I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
    Method m = context.getMethod();
    Object[] params = context.getParameters();
    Annotation[][] a = m.getParameterAnnotations();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].length > 0) {
            // this param has annotation(s)
        }
    }
```